# Bootstrap grid with fixed wrapper - Prevent columns from stacking up

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, grid, web-deployment, twitter-bootstrap-3

As the title says I'm trying to use Bootstrap 3 grid system with a fixed wrapper. But when I resize the Browser the columns stack up even if the wrapper stays the same size?

BTW: I'm using version 3 so that I can move to a responsive layout after I have ported the site. (Which is huge and I'm alone, so step by step is the only option ...)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="../../assets/js/html5shiv.js"></script>
      <script src="../../assets/js/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <style>
            /* Custom container */
            .container-fixed {
              margin: 0 auto;
              max-width: 800px;
              min-width: 800px;
              width: 800px;
                                  background-color:#C05659;
            }
            .container-fixed > hr {
              margin: 30px 0;
            }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
        <div class="container-fixed">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-4">.col-md-4</div>
              <div class="col-md-4">.col-md-4</div>
              <div class="col-md-4">.col-md-4</div>
            </div>
            <hr>
        </div>

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 65, accepted):

The `sm`,`md`,`lg`,etc.. cols wrap/stack responsively. Use the **non-stacking** `col-xs-*` class...

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4">.col-4</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">.col-4</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">.col-4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Demo: http://bootply.com/80085

***EDIT:***  **Bootstrap 4**, the `xs` no longer needs to be specified..

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-4">.col-4</div>
    <div class="col-4">.col-4</div>
    <div class="col-4">.col-4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I really feel embarrassed for not seeing this myself in the "grid options" section: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid