# How to center non stacking columns in twitter Bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm looking at the demo at in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18717422/4147870

Is there a way to center the columns to the middle of the page as opposed to being aligned to the left as it is in the demo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very easy to do. Use `container` rather than `container-fluid`. That example had an override for `container-fluid` that actually made it NOT fluid. If you remove the CSS you'll see that the content covers the space.

http://www.bootply.com/f0IoAp4e7J

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4">.col-4</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">.col-4</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">.col-4</div>
  </div>
  <hr>
</div>
```

Comment: What if there are only two columns and they are of different sizes? They become left aligned again http://www.bootply.com/qTyXoOD4U7

Comment: As long as they equal 12 (the Bootstrap Grid) they will work fine. Otherwise use an offset value like http://www.bootply.com/MvqVtpb0Jq.