# Prevent columns from wrapping in bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, animation

Similar to this question [Bootstrap 3 - grid with fixed wrapper - Prevent columns from stacking up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18715955/bootstrap-3-grid-with-fixed-wrapper-prevent-columns-from-stacking-up) I need to prevent my bootstrap columns from wrapping.

The issue I have however is that I need it to persist the not wrapping if more than 12 columns. As even with col-xs once you've got 12 columns, the thirteenth will wrap - as seen in this example bootply http://www.bootply.com/n5KdXfK7gZ#

If you look at the HTML from my bootply pictured below  - I want the fourth column (spare .col-4) to stay on the same row as the first 12 columns.

```
<div class="container-fixed">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4">.col-4</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">.col-4</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">.col-4</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">spare .col-4</div>
  </div>
  <hr>
</div>
```

I need my additional columns to continue on the same row as the first 12.  I don't mind if they scroll off the visible viewport creating a scroll bar, but I do not want them to wrap.

This is so that I can have a slide in / out animation, similar to bootstrap uis carousel, accept that I cannot use carousel, as I need it to behave completely differently when in deskop mode.

I hope this makes sense :)

Comment: Yes, it is in my example bootply.  I will edit the post to add it directly there too .....

Comment: Shouldn't it be `col-xs-3`? since `bootstrap` divides screen into 12 pieces of equal `width` when you assign `col-xs-4` there can be 3 Columns of length `4` which will be equal to `12`. From the link to question you provided, if you see that guy's question, he is maintaining `col-xs-4` for 3 elements not 4. Check **[this Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/n5KdXfK7gZ)** with `col-xs-3`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**LinKeCodes** Hi there.
To have **13** columns and to not have any drop down to a new row when resized.

Just divide the view width of the screen by 13, and create your own class of `col-13`.
You would need to write some css like this...

```
.col-13 {
    width: calc((100vw / 13 ) - 1vw); 
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    margin-left: 0.5vw;
    margin-right: 0.5vw;
    float: left;
}
```

Here is a working **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wdgdLvv4/)** for you to look at.

Hope this can help to get you on the right track here.

[image]

**ADDED TO THIS**
Here is an updated **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wdgdLvv4/1/embedded/result/)** using `overflow-x: scroll;` to help do what you want to add but hide the 13th block.

[image]

Comment: Hi AngularJR, that's kind of what i'm after.. however I don't really want the columns to resize so small.. I would rather that 12 still fit the viewport - and the 13th was 'off screen' whilst staying on the same 'row' rather than wrapping.

Comment: Hi, If 1 col is to be off screen, then this is not really responsive to fit screen sizes. You can use a or some media breakpoints with the `col-13` and say at a md screen size change the width value to break around half to a new row. let us know if you need help with breakpoints.

Comment: thanks for your help so far - I really appreciate it!, I am familiar with media break points.  It is responsive, because in desktop mode i'm happy for the 13th column to wrap ( i do use media breakpoints already to try to get this affect only when in 'mobile' mode ) - I need when in mobile mode for my columns not to wrap - this is so that I can slide the 13th column into view using an animation much the way a carousel works - so it needs to stay in line with all of the other columns - just off screen.

Comment: Take a look at my post above for the update. It has a scroll area hide to the 13th block to the right, without having the window width show a wider page.

Comment: thanks for the help I now have a solution :).  The final fiddle didn't work for me.. however with all of the comments plus your original fiddle - I now have a solution based off your advice :)  Here is my final fiddle - behaves as normal bootstrap 'desktop mode' however when using a smaller screen ( max width 796 ) it stops wrapping the columns.  https://jsfiddle.net/LinKeCodes/kauwjcjj/7

Comment: Hi there, Ok I see that you have this like you wanted now, well done. With the **inner** div that scrolls, you might try a fixed px width, that way the col-xx-xx will stay widther and not shrink when on very small screens. So that the info within can be easily read/seen. Great that you have it working now.

Comment: Use CSS box in the Fiddle to put the CSS instead of Style... will that work ?